# Lie derivative and Goldstone modes

Tags: quantum-field-theory, general-relativity, symmetry, ads-cft, axion

Systems with a gravity dual might experience the spontaneous breaking of a symmetry. In such a case, the dynamics of the dual QFT is determined by the Goldstone bosons.

But, what do the Goldstones look like in the gravity dual?

Take for example Sec. 3 of [1904.11445](https://arxiv.org/abs/1904.11445). Here translations along the $x_I$-direction are broken by mean of a scalar fields $\psi_I$ (the axions) which depend on the coordinates.

In the authors' own words:

> The Goldstone modes can be identified by acting on the background with the Lie derivative along $\partial/\partial \vec{x}$. It leaves all fields invariant except the $\psi_I$’s. This confirms that phonon dynamics are captured by the fluctuations $\delta \psi_I$.

Can anybody elaborate on this statement? Why does the Lie derivative identify the Goldstones?